# Conditionally formatting a cell in a pivot table based on a range of cells grouped by a Column Label

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, pivot-table, conditional-formatting

Within my pivot table I currently have cells conditionally formatted- Value=1, Green and Value=0, Yellow. I would like to conditionally format based upon all the values within a row label underneath a column label equalling zero.

Because this is a pivot table, the values will be dynamic as will the number of different column labels and subcolumn labels.  I basically don't care if ALL of the items for a given row label under a specific column label = 0, but I want attention brought to the cell if it is the only one (or two or three) underneath a header that = 0.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure, but perhaps this is the sort of answer you want:

[image: SU530008 example]

The default ('yellow') formula is `=ISNUMBER(G3)` and both rules are applied to All cells showing "Sum of C" values.

Note that as usual, pivot table will need refreshing before changes are 'recognised'.